# jQuery UI : disable draggable on a part of a div

Tags: jquery, html, window, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable div (let say A) that contains 2 divs (B and C). I want the drag-n-drop available when i click on the B div but not on the C. And when i drag B, C will also move.
In my C div i have a Highcharts div where i can zoom using drag n drop

I want the same behavior than a window. You can drag it when clicking on the title bar but not on the content. When you drag the title bar, the content move also.
In the example below, only #header and #nav should catch the draggle event and all divs will move

[image]

Thank you for help